# composer update datepicker local cache out of date

Tags: yii, datepicker, composer-php

so i want to update composer to use yii jui datepicker but i get this notif

http://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded f
rom the local cache and may be out of date
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

and when i using the use/datepicker (i forgot the syntax, sorry) it said there is error in vendor/... line 454 . so the composer doesnt install the package or something?

im newbie so can anyone help with simple language and detailed task, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please clear your composer cache first

`composer clear-cache`

Then continue diagnose the real problem why **packagist.org** could not be fully loaded

`composer diagnose`

Comment: Thank you so much for the `composer diagnose` command. I've been having issues where composer would be downloading very slowly. Seemed that I had no php-curl package installed (Ubuntu). Once installed my composer is fast. Thank you!!!!